# mod-rewrite spellbook

Tags: mod-rewrite, manual, reference-manual

Most online guides I've found are lengthy, boring, insufficient, or otherwise lacking. Where can I find a guide that explains mod-rewrite extensively, yet concisely?

(The above question sprouts from the following sentiment:)
I'm not satisfied with simply copying and pasting the magical incantations that make my .htaccess files do my bidding. I want to learn the dark arts. I want to learn the nooks and crannies of it, so that I can do tricky things specific to my server's needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the [detailed mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/). It contains everything you need to know. The rest is practice.

Comment: I had hoped for more hand-holding, but in truth the documentation really is well done.

Answer (score 0):

Well, one option I would suggest is not for free. Why not view slides **or** just buy the book written by Rich Bowen, one of the Apache contributors?:

http://www.apachelounge.com/download/contr/mod_rewrite.pdf

[http://www.amazon.com/Definitive-Guide-Apache-mod_rewrite-Guides/dp/1590595610](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590595610)

I am knocking through the book myself. Since I am actually testing out the directives, it is a slower read than I would prefer. But, think could be reasonably finished with three days of after-work effort. It was worth the price alone for me because it helped me understand. `RewriteMap`.  This saved my bacon at work when my team got surprised for an emergency implementation of over 200 redirects at one shot.